# When is it appropriate to use push in connections on typical american electrical outlets?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I quit using push in about 10 years ago when I realized it was causing issues when I had a few heaters plugged in at job sites.  My detective skills told me that 10 fried outlets over one winter and all 10 with the push-ins in use might be a clue to an issue.

So when can you use it?  And even more important why do manufacturers still produce them with that option (and if you want to take it a step further why does big box still sell them?) ?

See question [Why do electricians prefer not to use the push-in connections on receptacles?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53496/why-are-electricians-so-afraid-to-use-the-socket-push-in-connections) for more background.

Comment: As an opinion I'd say, always (code) acceptable; never advisable. Asking where they *aren't* code may be more appropriate. Also, I bet those outlets weren't pig-tailed. (If you find purchasable pig-tailed outlets and premade quad assemblies, let me know...)

Answer (score 1):

Code requires the wire to be **14 gauge copper** when back-stabbed into a device.
People buy them because stores sell them and they're easy to install. Personally, I blame 14 AWG; I only run 12 with 20A breakers. What is a nuisance trip? ;)

[What should I do with wires that are too large for back-stab terminals on a receptacles?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/what-should-i-do-with-wires-that-are-too-large-for-back-stab-terminals-on-a-rece)

Comment: You seriously blame the wire??? What kind of flawed logic is this? So you only run #12? Even for lighting and simple circuits? Personally I find this counterproductive. There is absolutely no reason typical resi lighting circuits need to be 20A. The "bigger is always better" mentality is not always best. I am very curious as to what your thinking is in blaming #14 for failed backstabs.